# Преобразование .wav файла NAudio C#

Tags: c#, wav, naudio

Необходимо выполнить преобразование .wav-файла по формуле

`0.5 x(n) + 0.25x(n-1) +0.25x(n-2) = y(n)`

Мой код:

```
// Считываем данные исходного wav файла
        using (var myReader = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(waveFilePath))
        {
            // Создание выходного файла.
            // (DF) - от Digital Filtration
            string newFilePath = waveFilePath.Replace(".wav", "(DF).wav");
            using (FileStream newWavFile = File.Create(newFilePath))
            {
                using (NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter writer = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileWriter(newWavFile, myReader.WaveFormat))
                {
                    // Считываем и выполняем преобразование
                    int bytesRead = 0;
                    var readSample = new byte[myReader.WaveFormat.SampleRate];
                    var tmpSample = new byte[myReader.WaveFormat.SampleRate];
                    do
                    {
                        // Считываем сэмпл
                        bytesRead = myReader.Read(readSample, 0, readSample.Length);
                        
                        // Преобразовываем по формуле
                        for (int n = 0; n < bytesRead; n++)
                        {
                            tmpSample[n] = (byte)(readSample[n] * 0.5);

                            // Формула
                            if (n >= 2)
                                tmpSample[n] = (byte)((readSample[n] * 0.5) + (readSample[n - 1] * 0.25) + (readSample[n - 2] * 0.25));
                            else if (n == 1)
                                tmpSample[n] = (byte)((readSample[n] * 0.5) + (readSample[n - 1] * 0.25));
                            else if (n == 0)
                                tmpSample[n] = (byte)((readSample[n] * 0.5));

                        }

                        writer.Write(tmpSample, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                    while (bytesRead != 0);
                }
            }

            // Выводим преобразованный файл на второй waveViewer
            customWaveViewerOutSignal.WaveStream = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFileReader(newFilePath);
            customWaveViewerOutSignal.FitToScreen();
        }
```

Однако на выходе получается нечто странное

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чём ошибка. Буду благодарен любой помощи и советам по коду

Comment: Это моно файл?.

Comment: Скорее всего нет. Не знаю, как точно определить. Но в WaveFormat стоит 2ch

Comment: Тогда вам надо его обрабатывать как последовательность `LRLRLRLR`, то есть четные с четными, нечетные с нечетными. Но для начала попробуйте с одноканальным моно-файлом.

Comment: Понял. Сейчас попробую найти одноканальный файл и попробовать с ним.

Comment: Еще значение амплитуды бывает 8 бит, бывает 16 бит, в зависимости от этого вам нужно выбирать либо `byte`, либо `ushort`. То есть если вы через этот фильтр прогоните 16-битный звук, у вас получится мусор типа того, что на втором графике. Потому что ваш фильтр подходит только для 8 бит.

Comment: Точно так и есть. WaveFormat указывает, что используется 16 бит. Спасибо. Попробую использовать ushort

Comment: Хмм, правда функция WaveFileReader.Read, которую я использую в myReader.Read использует в качестве первого аргумента byte[], и ushort туда не подходит. Я что-то не так делаю? Или нужно просто считывать байты как-то по-другому?

Comment: Какую версию .NET вы используете?

Comment: Для этого проекта .NetFramework 4.7.2

Comment: Жаль, тогда простых способов преобразовать массив байт в массив слов я не знаю. Знаю только для .NET Core 3.1 и новее. Читать и писать вам надо байты, все верно, а вот работать с парами байт надо как со `ushort`, где `ushort[0] = byte[0] + byte[1] * 256`

Comment: Лобо есть еще такой класс `BitConverter`, он может прочитать из массива байт нужный тип данных или записать, ему только смещение указать надо от начала массива.

Comment: Да, большое спасибо за подсказки. Буду действовать в этом направлении.